# What's the difference between a screen being attached and detached?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

```
[blah]$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
        16517.pts-0.blah       (01/28/2012 01:55:32 PM)        (Detached)
        4345.pts-1.blah     (01/27/2012 11:22:48 AM)        (Attached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-blahblah.
```

Got 2 questions

1) What's the difference between attached and detached screen

2) Can you kill attached and detached screen and how do you do it?
(I killed attached screen with screen -X -S id kill before but I don't think it works on detached one)

Comment: Is this a linux question?

Answer (score 9):

Attached means some process is actually using that session, detached means someone left the screen session running, but disconnected from it.

Why not simply connect to the screen sessions one at a time, and simply stop everything that is running?  Connect to existing sessions with the command `screen -r -d`, or `screen -R -D`.

Comment: Can you clarify what "a process is actually using that session?" Do you mean it is 'bound' to a terminal window/TTY/SSH session and it will close when that session closes? Or do you mean that there is an active process running in it?

Comment: How to check which screen I am in now if I have multiple screens when I use screen -ls ?

Comment: In the case of attached session is possible resume that in my case I close without close and appear now like attached and I don't wanna kill this process